# Form not passing POST data to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am passing in a reference to a file, and a string value `cardid`. For some reason when I return the result the `cardid` value is null. However when I view the page the `<h3>` header contains the string I expected. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML view**

```
<h3>@Model.CV.Id</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Tickets", FormMethod.Post, new { cardid=@Model.CV.Id, enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Attachment" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(string cardid,IFormFile file)
{
    ......
    string res="yay";
    return Ok(new {cardid=cardid,res=res });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include `cardid` in your form. You are simply creating an attribute on `<form>`, which does nothing.

```
<h3>@Model.CV.Id</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Tickets", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="cardid" value="@(Model.CV.Id)" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Attachment" />
}
```

You could also include `cardid in the action:

```
Html.BeginForm("UploadFile?cardid=" + Model.CV.Id, "Tickets", FormMethod.Post...)
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion of adding a new input and just got a textbox appearing (type cardid doesnt work). I tried you second and could no longer find the route (because the controller cant handle adding a GET param to a POST request in the same query I believe)

Comment: Sorry, I fudged the `<input>`. It should be a hidden field. I updated my answer.

Comment: Haha, I should have realized.... your first suggestion works perfectly now! Thanks